# How to write custom comparator for std::set<std::pair<int,int>> where first element of pair must be unique

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I am having trouble writing a strict weak ordering comparator for `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` such that the first element of an inserted pair must be unique in the set, and the second elements of the pairs must be in descending order.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct Comparator {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& lhs, const std::pair<int, int>& rhs) {
        if (lhs.first == rhs.first) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return lhs.second > rhs.second;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::set<std::pair<int, int>, Comparator> s;
    
    s.emplace(1, 1);
    s.emplace(2, 0);
    s.emplace(2, 2);

    for (auto e : s) {
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Expected output:

```
1 1
2 0
```

Actual output:

```
2 2
1 1
2 0
```

How do I enforce uniqueness of the first element of the pair?

Comment: Whenever [an ordering function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) doesn't work, it's a good bet that it's because it break the [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set` assumes that the keys are ordered based off a set of axioms known as [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order) they give a programmer-friendly set of rules.

It requires:

Irreflexitive:

```
!( a < a )
```

Transitive:

```
(a < b) and (b < c) means (a < c)
```

then, define `weak_equivalent(a,b)` to mean `!(a<b) and !(b<a)` -- ie, neither element is less than each other, so under `<` we are "equivalent".  Then this equivalence relation is transitive (and obviously reflexitive):

```
weak_equivalent(a,b) and weak_equivalent(b,c) means weak_equivalent(a,c)
```

ie, `weak_equivalent` describes a bundle of elements that are all equal to each other.

In your case, you appear to want all elements (x,_) to be equivalent under your `<`.

And you want it to otherwise be ordered by the second element (backwards, but that isn't important to me).

But (1,5) < (2,3) and (2,3) < (1,1), which means (1,5) < (1,1) by the transitive requirement.

That disagrees with your requirement that (1,5) and (1,1) is equivalent.

So `std::set` cannot support this ordering.

In general, sorting when you aren't at least a strict weak ordering is difficult, because there isn't a consistent order to your elements.

In your case, you should probably stop using a `std::set` directly.

```
struct my_special_container {
  std::map<int, int> m_s;

  void emplace_if_not_exist( int a, int b ) {
    auto it = m_s.find(b);
    if (it != m_s.end()) {
      m_s[b] = a;
    }
  }
};
```

now you just have to write an iterator that returns the elements; the `map` iterator does it backwards compared to your requirements.

Comment: Would a std::multiset support such an ordering?

Comment: @TheMemeMachine multiset also requires a strict weak ordering, so no.  The only difference for multi is how it handles equivalent elements.